# Rails throw NoMethodError in production mode but not in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, nomethoderror

I have the following code:

```
module Api
module V1

class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController

  def succeed_with_object(data, status_code = 200)
    render json: {success: true, data_type: 'object', data: data.as_json}, status: status_code
  end

end

end
end
```

In which `ApplicationController` is the parent controller for all my api controllers. And ::ApplicationController is the parent controller in web controllers. And then I have

```
module Api
module V1

class AppController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

  def android
    file_name = "app-latest-#{ANDROID_VERSION}.apk"
    app = MobileApp.new('android', ANDROID_VERSION, "http://example.com/download/#{file_name}")
    succeed_with_object(app)
  end

end

end
end
```

Then when I visit http://example.com/api/v1/app/android in production mode, I run into

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `succeed_with_object' for #<Api::V1::AppController:0x0000000569bbd0>):
app/controllers/api/v1/app_controller.rb:11:in `android'
```

But it works all fine in development mode. I wonder if the inheritance hierarchy is somewhat different between production mode and development mode.

Comment: Try renaming your Application Controller to anything else and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try having this structure:

```
class Api::V1::ApiController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
end
```

This is will be the parent controller for your all controllers for API.

Then you can use the above ApiController to extend your api controllers.

```
class Api::V1::TransactionsController < Api::V1::ApiController
end
```